# classpath is deprecated, kotlin 1.7.0

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, classpath

I have used `classpath` in my kotlin project.

but `classpath`  is deprecated in kotlin 1.7.0.

refer to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#deprecations-and-removals

```
In the notes for Kotlin 1.7.0 that the KotlinCompile task still had the deprecated Kotlin property classpath, which would be removed in future releases.
```

What should I use instead of classpath?

Also, how should I use it?

It would be very helpful if you could give me a sample code.

If there is anyone who understands, thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `plugins` block instead in your project `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
plugins { 
     id("com.android.library") version "$agp_version" apply false 
     id("com.android.application") version "$agp_version" apply false 
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "$kotlin_version" apply false 
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "$kotlin_version" apply false 
     id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "$hilt_version" apply false 
     id("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "$nav_version" apply false 
     id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "$google_services_version" apply false 
     id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "$crashlytics_version" apply false 
 }
```

Here's the full file [link](https://github.com/atick-faisal/Safety-Android/blob/main/build.gradle#L60-L69).

Comment: I'm sorry for replying late,  "com.android.tools.build:gradle" was errored. Do you know this error ? error -> Plugin id contains is invalid char  ':'

Comment: You should replace the ":" in the plugin names with "." However, I don't think you need this plugin anymore. The `library` and `application` plugins should be enough.